# Запятая перед "и чтобы"

Tags: запятые, сложное-предложение

Прошу помочь, нужна ли запятая перед "и чтобы". Не могу разобраться, какое правило применимо в данном случаи:
Благодарим вас за этот нелегкий труд и желаем сибирского здоровья, отличного настроения (,) и чтобы каждый день приносил удовлетворение от сделанного!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятой не нужно. Правило в данном случае называется **Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами:** http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100 Обобщающее слово там — *желаем*: «желаем (...) здоровья, (...) настроения и чтобы каждый день (...)».